# Handling Character Set in Informatica

Tags: oracle11g, openedge, informatica, informatica-powercenter, progress-db

We have a Scenario where Progress DB is my source and we have a ETL job which will load data reading from Progress and loads to Oracle , but some character set needs to be handled like below.

```
. Some bullet points
. Are being converted as?
. Need to convert again to bullet.
```

In the above example the bullet points are being stored in oracle end as

```
? Some bullet points
? Are being converted as?
? Need to convert again to bullet.
```

Please suggest  is there any way to handle this in Informatica or Modifying the Query of Progress or Oracle .

Comment: try using `CLOB` datatype

Comment: What encoding do you have at Informatica Server and Oracle database level?

Comment: You don't say what character set was used to store the data in the first place.  Progress supports a number of connection parameters related to character encoding.  (The parameter names all start with "-cp".)  The selected code pages need to support whatever is required to pass these bullet points through from end to end and must, of course, also be compatible with however the data was stored to start with.  Oracle and Informatica also need to also have corresponding values set in a compatible manner.  It isn't so much "modifying the query" as it is setting the proper connection options.